# Swift: Recursive Loop and Flatten Array

Tags: arrays, swift, recursion

I want to better understand recursive looping and flatten in Swift or any other language for that matter.

I have a simple Swift class

```swift
class Survey { 
      let items: [SurveyItem]?
}

class SurveyItem { 
      let id: String?
      let items: [SurveyItem]?
}
```

A Survey has `items` and each `item` can have more types of its own.

I want to write a function which assembles all items and subitems in a survey into a single flat array

Comment: I would avoid using nullable collections. Just model empty case with an empty collection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
protocol SurveyItemVending {
    var items: [SurveyItem]? { get }
}

extension Survey: SurveyItemVending { }
extension SurveyItem: SurveyItemVending { }

extension SurveyItemVending {
    var allItemsRecursively: [SurveyItem] {
        let items = self.items ?? []
        return items + items.flatMap { $0.allItemsRecursively }
    }
}
```

Now you can ask any `Survey` or `SurveyItem` for its `allItemsRecursively`.